# Select manipulation on a list

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, ionic-framework

I have a list, as soon as I select my last item of the list, I want it to always select the first one.

Is there a way to do this ?

[image: Here's an image of my list]

```
<ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selecteduser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user._id">
      </ion-content>{{ getUserNickname(user }} </ion-option>
    <ion-option  (ionSelect)="openConfigPage()" >Configuration</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

So I want when I click on my configuration, it will select the first item of my list

There is my ts

```
openConfigPage() {
    this.selectedUser = this.users[0]; // Will select the first item of the list 
    this.navCtrl.push(ConfigPage)
}

selectUser(userId: string) {
    this.selectedUser = this.users.find(b => b._id === userId)
    this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)
}
```

Is there a way to do it with the DOM ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `isUserSelected` as a boolean array then populate it like this:

```
openConfigPage() {
    this.isUserSelected = this.users.map((e, i) => {
      return (i === 0) ? true : false; 
    });
    this.navCtrl.push(ConfigPage)
}
```

Then in `html` side use `selected` attribute like this:

```
<ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selecteduser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" [value]="i" [selected]="isUserSelected[i]" (ionSelect)="selectUser(i)">
      </ion-content>{{ getUserNickname(user }} </ion-option>
    <ion-option  (ionSelect)="openConfigPage()" >Configuration</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Also, don't forget to update the value of `isUserSelected`(boolean array) when the user selects something (in `selectUser()` method).

```
selectUser(id) {
    this.selectedUser = this.users[id];
    this.isUserSelected = this.isUserSelected.map((v, i) => (i === id) ? true : false);
    this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/option/Option/).

Comment: Is there a way to do it with something like this ? 

document.getElementsByClassName('somethin').selectIndex

Comment: @julia456124645 I don't think direct DOM manipulation is recommended when using an library like angular.

Comment: got error  : type boolean[] is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Comment: @julia456124645 Did you declared `isUserSelected` as `isUserSelected : boolean[] = []` ?

Comment: Thank you sir, got an error arguments are not aligned on : this.navCtrl.push(ConfigPage)

Comment: @julia456124645 that is a different question. Please post a new question with related codes. And if this answer helped you please mark it a accepted. :)

Comment: @julia456124645 I've updated `openConfigPage()` please check.

Comment: It's acting weirdly, it only work the first time.
If i select again it will not select the first one:/

Comment: @julia456124645 As mentioned in answer did you updated `selectUser()` method accordingly(To update the `isUserSelected boolean array` whenever an option is selected)?

Comment: could you please tell me how to update it the isUserSelected in my selectUser() ?Thank you sir, we are near the solution.

Comment: please show your `onChange()` method. Actually u'll need to modify it, so that it will update `isUserSelected` array.

Comment: Sorry sir there isn't an onChange(), forget to delete it from my question.
I only have an (ngModelChange)="selectUser$event)">

Comment: The problem is when i select configuration it will only work the first time if i select it again, it will not select the first item. i need to select another item and select again the configuration item

Comment: @julia456124645 Updated my answer. **Also**, notice the `[value]="i"` in `<ion-option`

Comment: This is not working. problem with value ..
It's not possible to do it with the DOM, i think it's the best solution, with this way i'm sure even if i select the last item it will directly select the first one

Comment: @julia456124645 please try the newer `selectUser()` method

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined.

sorry i wasted your time

Comment: this happens because `this.users` array is undefined till that point. I'll suggest you to remove that portion of code & try again.

Comment: Even with that it's not working :'( .
I'm pretty sure doign a DOM manipulation is the solution.